# Getting undefined when accessing javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having a weird issue with an object on react native.
The object is as follows:
Doing a :

```
console.log(data);
```

Shows:

```
Object {
  "data": Object {
    "size": 40,
    "team": "yellow",
  },
}
```

But then accesing the object....
Doing a:

```
console.log(data.size);
```

I get :

```
undefined
```

Why? How I have to do it to access the size?

Thanks

Comment: Try `data.data.size`...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do this,

```
console.log(data.data.size);
```

```js
const data = {
  "data": {
    "size": 40,
    "team": "yellow",
  },
}

console.log(data.data.size)
```

the is `data` object inside data. So, u also have to access that `data` for `size`

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = { data: { size: 40 }};
```

So it should be `data.data.size`